# how to compare 2 csv files using pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

**I have 2 csv files sorted on ID.**

*File1.csv*

```
ID  X   Y   Z    
1   10  20  30    
3   23  12  15    
5   40  50  60
```

*File2.csv*

```
ID  X   Y   Z    
1   5   10  15    
2   40  50  60    
5   55  12  22
```

I want to iterate through both the files and look at the ID ( row[0]) and do two operations:

If both IDs exist (here "1" and "5"), then add this record in new file named diff.csv

```
ID x1 x2 diffx y1 y2 diffy  z1 z2 diffz    
1  10 20 -10   20 10 10     30 15 15    
5  40 55 -15   50 12 38     60 22 38
```

**If ID exist in only 1st file, then add this id in onlyf1.csv**

```
ID    
3
```

**If ID exist in only 2nd file, then add this id in onlyf2.csv**

```
ID    
2
```

I can think of just reading the files in pandas.

```
f1 = pd.read_csv("File1.csv")

f2 = pd.read_csv("File2.csv")
```

Can anyone help me on how to filter out the data and do operations on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can `merge` it first,then `groupby` columns, after get the `diff`, we can `concat` it back to the merged df

```
s=df1.merge(df2,on = 'ID', how = 'inner')
t=s.groupby(np.array(s.columns.str.split('_').str[0]),axis=1).diff().dropna(axis=1).add_suffix('DIFF')
pd.concat([s,t],axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
Out[896]: 
   ID  X_x  X_y  X_yDIFF  Y_x  Y_y  Y_yDIFF  Z_x  Z_y  Z_yDIFF
0   1   10    5     -5.0   20   10    -10.0   30   15    -15.0
1   5   40   55     15.0   50   12    -38.0   60   22    -38.0
```